# Manipulating two list into a single list of two dimensions

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list

```
A = {1,2,3}
```

and

```
B = {4,5,6}
```

Is there a quick way to produce C out of A and B such that

```
C = {{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}}
```

That is, 1 is with 4, 2 with 5 and 3 with 6.

Comment: `Transpose[{A,B}]`.

Comment: In addition to `Transpose`, `Thread` can also be useful here because it allows you to push other heads into a list. E.g., `Thread[A -> B]` gives `{1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6}`.

Comment: In addition++, Flatten may be used to transpose a 'ragged' array.  `BB= {4,5,6,7}; Flatten[{A,BB},{{2}}]` -- {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {7}}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MapThread[List, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]

(*   {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}   *)
```

Have fun!